# Where is the ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, roleprovider, activedirectorymembership

I´ve read in MCT Trainer Handbook of course 20486:

> **Role Providers in ASP.NET 4.5**
>
> **ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider**. This provider class is defined in the System.Web.Security namespace, and the provider enables you to use Active Directory as the management model for roles

This namespace (System.Web.Security) has the **ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider** class but not the **ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider** one? Is this statement correct or I´m missing something?

Thanks

Comment: have you consulted this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478950.aspx

Comment: this seems self explanatory
`Inheritance Hierarchy
System.Object 
  System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderBase
    System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
      System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider
Namespace:  System.Web.Security
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)`

Comment: @djkraze, I´m not looking for ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class. I´m looking for ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider.

Comment: http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html

Comment: @djkraze, I think that you do not understand my question. I do not want to create a CUSTOM Active Directory Role Provider. What I am questioning is the fact that the 20486 course Trainer Handbook is stating that there is a Built-in ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider.

Comment: sorry I did not understand